# How to change path in Ninja IDE for windows?

Tags: python, windows, ninja

Im a newbie to python and starting to learn Ninja IDE seemed good. but when trying to import "telnetlib" module from within the NINJA I get error:

```
>>> import telnetlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named telnetlib
>>>
```

I successfully import modules like "sys" and "time".

Results of sys.path:

```
>>> sys.path
['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Ninja\\Ninja.exe']
>>>
```

I already have C:\python27\ folders in path and also created a system environment variable called PYTHONPATH as mentioned here:
[How to add to the pythonpath in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)

It Works fine when using python for windows (from python.org).

Thanks

Comment: you say you already have `C:\python27\ ` on the path, but it is very clearly not on `sys.path`, what is `sys.path` when you run python from python.org?

Comment: I didn't know they are different.
from python on windows.

>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', 'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\idlelib', 'C:\\Python27', 'C:\\Python27\\Lib', 'C:\\Python27\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']

How to change sys.path?

Comment: [You can modify it using standard list operations:](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#standard-modules)  `import sys ; sys.path.append('/ufs/guido/lib/python')`

Comment: Hi,Im looking for a way to have the path for every project and not have to do it every time I start a new project